# Borderlands 2 skins in backpack?

Tags: borderlands-2

The new backpack update that categorizes your weapons, how do you get to the skins to activate? They are no longer listed on the right with shields and grenades.

Comment: They should still be there. Is this a new update? Like today?

Comment: Skins were always applied in those kiosks.  Did they change something so they automatically get added?  Also, what platform?

Comment: PS3... just did a DLC yesterday. Now my gun inventory is categorized (sniper, submach, shotgun, etc) for only unequipped weapons off to the right of the equipped wepons. Dont see any extra skins, relics, granades and shields that are not equiped.(which you could see before if you scrolled down) Only time it is ALL visable is when shopping at a vending machine. No way to activate skins....but you can sell them ???

Answer (score 5):

There has been no such 'backpack update that categorizes your weapons'; the option to have your backpack contents sorted by category has been available since the game released.

Go back into your inventory, and look at the various listings for what buttons you can press; one of them will be to change the way it's sorted (I believe this is <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and/or <kbd>Pg Down</kbd> on PC). One of the sorting methods is to sort by gun category, which hides non-gun items you're holding. Switching to something else should make any skins you have in your inventory become visible.

Comment: I'm not in-game to confirm, but I believe the rotation is type (weapons/shields/etc) -> weapon type -> manufacturer.